# Swift UITextField resize

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to make one app for iPhone 5,6,6+. So, every element it must be to resize it. I can't resize `UITextField`.

The only way I found is calling `self.view.addSubview()`. It works if I want to make the `UITextField` larger, but not smaller. How can I change current `UITextField`?

Can you suggest something?

Comment: Isn't that what autolayout is all about? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: You should be using autolayout if you want to make an app do that easily. If you have attempted something in code, please show your work and describe how it does not behave how you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and probably [Auto Layout’s Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html).

To future proof you may want to use [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1) as well, but I’ll digress on that.

I’ll include an example of how to do this programmatically for something simple like a UILabel since the coding part seems to trip people up more than the Interface Builder stuff.  You can Google Interface Builder Auto Layout tutorials if you want to go that route.

Auto Layout uses NSLayoutConstraints to describe how one view is laid out with respect to another.  You can create these constraints and add them to the “parent” view (the containing view holding the other views).  View controller’s have a default view named “view” that you probably add most of your stuff to so we'll just add the constraints to that. Visual Format Language is slightly less typing and a tiny bit more intuitive, so I’ll do an example using that, but if you come across something it can't do you can look up how to create the constraints without Visual Format Language.

Here’s an example of a UILabel with a width of 100 and a height of 50 using Auto Layout’s Visual Format Language:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // First add the label to the parent view
  let label = UILabel()
  label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) // Not needed when using Auto LayoutS
  label.text = “Test Label”
  label.sizeToFit() // We didn’t pass a frame/rect to UILabel() so this gives it an intrinsic size
  view.addSubview(label)

  // Create an NSLayoutConstraint for the width and add it to the parent view
  let labelWidthConstraint: NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary) // This uses Auto Layout’s Visual Format Language, which is what the H:[label(100)] part is, and is a *little* simpler than creating constraints normally.
  view.addConstraints(labelWidthConstraint)

  // Create an NSLayoutConstraint for the height and add it to the parent view
  let labelHeightConstraint: NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[label(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
  view.addConstraints(labelHeightConstraint)
}
```

NOTE: You need to call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) on the views you create in order for them to use Auto Layout, but DON’T call this on the “parent” view, like the main view that comes with a View Controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can look up other Visual Format Language strings to position views as well.  I just used width and height since I already had a good example ready.